# Why do I have Syntax error on first colon, but only on some devices(all windows 10)

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have to run a code that doesnt execute

```
class CImport_Object():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ticket = {}
        self.actions = []
        self.tasks = []
        self.memo:CMemo = None
        self.attachments = []
```

It gets an error at the self.memo:CMemo line

```
  File ".\01_requ_table.py", line 49
self.memo:CMemo = None
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This code does work on other systems, but I'm clueless.
I checked python versions (3.8.3) and windows versions with the systems that do execute this code.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error. Are you sure you're running python 3.8? What's the output of `sys.version_info`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you run the code with different versions of Python. That is a type hint, and valid syntax since 3.5 but not in e.g. 2.7 where it gives a syntax error. So when you get that error you are not using 3.8.

You can verify the version you are running with by adding this to the code, works both in 3 and 2:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

If you have multiple versions of Python installed, Windows has one of them associated with .py files, so you can fix that .. might be easiest and clearest to just remove 2 and reinstall 3.

Comment: ``print(sys.version)`` also works on Python2, and provides the exact same output as ``print sys.version``.

Comment: ah good point, for 2.7 at least, I think it doesn't work in 2.6 and older though but probably not many places have that anymore

Comment: It will also work for older versions. Plain ``(x)`` is just ``x``. The difference is for e.g. ``print("The version is", sys.version)`` which will use and output a ``tuple`` on Py2; it will still *work*, just not look quite as nice.

Comment: I'm pretty sure print('x') is an error in 2.6 because there is no built-in print function .. for it to evaluate ('x') wouldn't there need to be a space between print and ( ? .. didn't find an online repl with 2.6 and don't have it installed at hand and gtg now

Comment: Nope, you are right, print('x') works even in 2.3 .. this was bugging me so had to try. I was almost sure that got errors in Py 2 sometimes when tried to use print like a function, and had to go and remove the parenthesis when brought some 3 code over. But can't imagine now what that could have been about. Maybe I just recall wrong and it was about adding the parenthesis when went to 3. Live and learn! Thanks for the note.

Comment: Solved thanks to the reference to 3.5. I did install 3.8, and this was the only version shown by windows but there was a version 3.5 of Python included with the installation of Veloview which was used as default by windows.